# Error al instalar SQL Server Managment 2014 Express (Error code 0x858C0038)

Tags: sql-server

Al momento de terminar de configurarlo y y apunto de instalar me sale este mensaje:

```
SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

The required MSI package 'C:\Users\alejandro\Downloads\SQLEXPR_x64_ESN\2058_ESM_LP\x64\setup\sqlsupport_msi\SqlSupport.msi' doesn't exist. 

Error code 0x858C0038.
```

Me dice que no existe dicho componente y se para la instalación, que puedo descargar o configurar para que pueda avanzar la instalación.

Comment: Descarga nuevamente, me late que el archivo está corrupto

Comment: Opino lo mismo que el gran @fredyfx, la solución más obvia pareciera ser esa. Aunque también asegúrate de tener permisos de administrador y/o permisos de lectura y escritura en las carpetas que indicas ;)

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente link de documentación de microsoft, podrás ver la forma de arreglar tu instalación.

https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/969052/how-to-restore-the-missing-windows-installer-cache-files-and-resolve-p

Procedimiento 1: Utilice una secuencia de comandos

Para completar los pasos de este procedimiento, deberá copiar la secuencia de comandos de FindSQLInstalls.vbs de la sección "Más información" en una carpeta local en el equipo donde está intentando actualizar su instalación de SQL Server.

Nota: La secuencia de comandos FindSQLInstalls.vbs recopila la información para corregir las rutas de acceso del paquete no es válido. Y esta secuencia de comandos se utiliza con las ubicaciones de origen para asegurarse de que todos los paquetes MSP están en el directorio de caché de Windows Installer. Si está disponible el medio original, se vuelven a agregar los paquetes que faltan.

Para resolver estos problemas mediante una secuencia de comandos, siga estos pasos:
Busque el directorio en el que guardó el contenido de la secuencia de comandos.
Abra un símbolo del sistema con privilegios elevados para el directorio en el que guardó la secuencia de comandos y ejecute el siguiente comando:
Cscript FindSQLInstalls.vbs %computername%_sql_install_details.txt
Abra el archivo desde el paso 2 en un editor de texto como el Bloc de notas e identificar los problemas que están causando el error. Para ello, busque el archivo de texto para los modelos de cadena como la siguiente:
No
!!!
Basándose en los resultados en el paso 3, siga los pasos que sean necesarios.

Nota: Buscar más información acerca de estos pasos en la sección "Ejemplos".

Repita los pasos del 2 al 4 hasta que el archivo de texto que se creó en el paso 2 ya no contiene texto que hace referencia a las rutas no válidas o los archivos que faltan para el componente que se está actualizando.

Ejemplos

Los siguientes ejemplos son entradas y explicaciones de las acciones que se describen en el archivo de salida que se genera cuando se ejecuta la secuencia de comandos FindSQLInstalls.vbs.

Ejemplo 1: Faltan archivos de instalador

El siguiente es un ejemplo de la salida que se genera cuando falta un paquete .msi en la carpeta de caché de Windows Installer.

```
================================================================================
PRODUCT NAME   : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Database Engine Services
================================================================================
  Product Code: {9FFAE13C-6160-4DD0-A67A-DAC5994F81BD}
  Version     : 10.2.4000.0
  Most Current Install Date: 20110211
  Target Install Location: 
  Registry Path: 
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\C31EAFF906160DD46AA7AD5C99F418DB\SourceList
     Package    : sql_engine_core_inst.msi
  Install Source: \x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\
  LastUsedSource: m;1;G:\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\
```

La línea "LastUsedSource" señala a la ubicación que se utilizó para ejecutar el programa de instalación.

En la línea "LastUsedSource", la entrada m; significa media e indica que el origen de los medios de CD o DVD.

En el ejemplo siguiente, el origen es un CD o un DVD en la unidad G. Si se produjo la instalación desde una carpeta de archivos o desde un recurso compartido de red, la línea empieza con una entrada Norte; "LastUsedSource" seguido de una entrada de Numeric_Data_Name; y la ruta de acceso real:

```
!!!! sql_engine_core_inst.msi DOES NOT exist on the path in the path G:\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\ !!!!
Action needed, re-establish the path to G:\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\
```

La "acción necesaria" línea muestra la ruta de acceso completa que debe existir para poder actualizar los archivos que faltan para el medio de instalación original:

```
Installer Cache File: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\19b4d2.msi
```

La línea "Archivo de caché del instalador" Confirma el nombre del archivo de caché de instalador:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!! C:\WINDOWS\Installer\19b4d2.msi DOES NOT exist in the Installer cache. !!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

La siguiente sección de la salida informa de las acciones que se requieren para resolver los archivos que faltan:

```
 Action needed, recreate or re-establish path to the directory:
     G:\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\then rerun this script to update installer cache and results
     The path on the line above must exist at the root location to resolve
     this problem with your msi/msp file not being found or corrupted,
     In some cases you may need to manually copy the missing file or manually
     replace the problem file overwriting it is exist: 

     Copy "G:\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\sql_engine_core_inst.msi" C:\WINDOWS\Installer\19b4d2.msi

     Replace the existing file if prompted to do so.
```

Ejemplo 2: Las revisiones que faltan

Las revisiones que faltan pueden producir entradas similares a las del ejemplo 1. La mayoría de los casos, observará que las entradas en la línea "LastUsedSource Patch" que hacen referencia a una revisión y esta línea es similar a la siguiente:

```
Patch LastUsedSource:   n;1;c:\0ca91e857a4f12dd390f0821a3\HotFixSQL\Files\
```

Este resultado indica lo siguiente acerca de la instalación de la revisión:

> Se instaló la revisión original haciendo doble clic en el archivo ejecutable de la revisión.
>   El instalador de la revisión utiliza una carpeta temporal, c:\0ca91e857a4f12dd390f0821a3, durante la instalación de la revisión.
>   Para volver a crear la ruta de acceso, debe ejecutar el mismo ejecutable y agregar el siguiente parámetro:
>   /x:c:\0ca91e857a4f12dd390f0821a3
>   Nota: Este comando hace que el archivo ejecutable para extraer los archivos a la ubicación anterior de falta y se vuelve a crea la estructura que se requiere para actualizar la caché de Windows installer con los archivos que faltan. La ubicación real variará y que tenga una única revisión como un service pack que se extraen en varias ubicaciones. Cada producto instalado, incluye una sección que contiene la siguiente información para "Parches instalados":
>   Display name:
>   KB Article URL:  http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=
>   Patch LastUsedSource:

La línea "URL de artículo de KB" puede ayudar a descargar cualquier medio de la revisión, si es necesario.

Procedimiento 2: Restaurar manualmente los archivos

Para restaurar manualmente los archivos que faltan de la caché de Windows Installer, siga estos pasos:
Recopilar todos los detalles sobre el archivo que falta desde el mensaje de error, desde el archivo de registro de instalación o de las entradas del registro que son mantenidas por el instalador de Windows. Por ejemplo, en el mensaje de Error 1 en la sección "Síntomas", toda la información necesaria para resolver el problema está presente en el mensaje de error:
PatchName: "revisión 1702 para SQL Server 2008 R2 (KB981355) (64 bits)"
Archivo MSP original utilizado por la revisión de seguridad: sql_engine_core_inst.msp
Archivo MSP en caché: c:\Windows\Installer\1fdb1aec.msp
Si no tiene todos los detalles, consulte la sección "Más información para el procedimiento 2" para conocer los pasos recopilar estos detalles.

Visite http://support.microsoft.comy busque el artículo KB que se asocia con esta revisión. En este ejemplo, debe buscar KB981355.
Descargar este paquete de revisión en el equipo. Asegúrese de descargar el paquete de revisión que corresponde a la plataforma requerida. En este ejemplo, el paquete es SQLServer2008R2-KB981355-x64.exe.
Extraiga el contenido del paquete de revisiones mediante la sintaxis siguiente:

```
C:\Temp>SQLServer2008R2-KB981355-x64.exe /x C:\Temp\SQLServer2008R2-KB981355-x64\
```

Busque el archivo de sql_engine_core_inst.msp de archivo msp original. El archivo debe estar en la carpeta siguiente:

```
C:\Temp\SQLServer2008R2-KB981355-x64\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\
```

Copie este archivo msp original a la caché de Windows Installer siguiente:

```
%windir%\installer\
Cambie el nombre del archivo msp original, sql_engine_core_inst.msp, a la siguiente:
1fdb1aec.msp de archivo msp en caché
```

Puede iniciar el programa de instalación de la actualización que se produjo el error y reanudar el proceso de actualización. Puede encontrar este mensaje para un archivo de caché de Windows Installer que falta para otro componente u otra actualización del mismo producto.

Para obtener una lista de todos los archivos que faltan Windows Installer caché que están relacionados con los componentes del producto de SQL Server, puede descargar la herramienta de SQL Server 2008 R2 BPA que se menciona en la sección "Más información".

Si el mensaje de error hace referencia a un archivo de base de datos de Windows Installer (.msi) que faltan, no es necesario realizar los pasos 2 a 4. En su lugar, puede ir directamente al paso 5. Tiene que localizar el archivo .msi desde el medio original que usó para instalar el producto. Si este mensaje de error se generó para sql_engine_core_inst.msi, tienes que buscar este archivo desde el medio de instalación en la estructura de carpetas siguiente:

```
\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\
```

Los demás pasos son los mismos.

Para obtener más información para el procedimiento 2

Cómo obtener el paquete de revisión y los detalles del producto que falta un archivo .msp

Diferentes versiones del producto, generan mensajes de error diferentes para este problema. Aparecen los mensajes de error que se mencionan en la sección "Síntomas" para programas de instalación de actualizaciones a partir de Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP1. Para otras actualizaciones, recibirá mensajes de error que no se pueden especificar con claridad el qué archivo de revisión no existe en la caché de Windows Installer y los detalles de la actualización específica. Estos mensajes de error, los archivos de registro de configuración contendrá información sobre el archivo de caché de Windows Installer que falta. Ejemplo de registro de instalación similar al siguiente:

```
MSI (s) (FC:F8) [13:48:58:649]: Opening existing patch 'C:\WINDOWS\Installer\145258.msp'.
MSI (s) (FC:F8) [13:48:58:649]: Couldn't find local patch 'C:\WINDOWS\Installer\145258.msp'. Looking for it at its source.
MSI (s) (FC:F8) [13:48:58:649]: Resolving Patch source.
MSI (s) (FC:F8) [13:48:58:649]: Note: 1: 2203 2: D:\cda162709d239766830bae5ce12b\HotFixSQL\Files\sqlrun_sql.msp 3: -2147287037 
MSI (s) (FC:F8) [13:48:58:649]: SOURCEMGMT: Source is invalid due to missing/inaccessible package.
MSI (s) (FC:F8) [13:49:29:961]: Product: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -- Installation failed.
MSI (s) (FC:F8) [13:49:29:992]: MainEngineThread is returning 1635
This patch package could not be opened.  Verify that the patch package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer patch package.
D:\SQL2K5\Servers\Setup\SqlRun_SQL.msi
```

Si examina cuidadosamente el registro de la instalación, ya proporciona la información sobre el archivo MSP Original que se utilizó la revisión siguiente:

```
sqlrun_sql.msp
```

Para obtener más detalles acerca del archivo .msp que faltan en la caché de Windows Installer, siga estos pasos:

```
Busque el archivo .msp que falta en la siguiente subclave del registro de revisiones de Windows Installer:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Patches\
Encontrar el GUID de la revisión.
Buscar el GUID de la revisión en la siguiente subclave del registro de productos de Windows Installer:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\
Para el registro de instalación de ejemplo, la información sobre el archivo .msp que falta y los detalles de revisión correspondientes están presentes en las entradas del registro siguientes:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Patches\A3B085EA74A9A7640A496636F7EF9A44
Valor: 0

Nombre: LocalPackage

Datos: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\145258.msp


HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\1EB3A031CC585314E87AA527E46EECC2\Patches\A3B085EA74A9A7640A496636F7EF9A44 Valor: 6

Nombre: DisplayName

Datos: GDR 2050 para SQL Server la base de datos Services 2005 ENU (KB932555)
```

Ahora dispone de todos los puntos de información para iniciar los pasos para resolver los archivos que faltan en la caché de Windows Installer.

Nota: Si utiliza Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3 (SP3) o una versión posterior, también puede recibir un mensaje de error similar para los archivos .msi que faltan. Mediante el uso de este mensaje de error, puede determinar rápidamente qué archivo falta, qué service pack para descargar, y donde se puede encontrar la descarga.